# cant inject $modal in angular module

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im bulding an AngularJS app. as part of this app, I need a modal popup. I got this working in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FtH8hkuaEj5A2zhMJdnE?p=preview
But when I try to implement it into the actual app, I get an error when injecting the $modal in any module.

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20webpartnerController

I have 
angular v1.5.7 
angular-ui/ui-bootstrap v2.3.1

Module:

```
var app = angular.module("webpartner", [
    "ui.router", "" +
    "angularSpinner",
    "ngMaterial",
    "material.svgAssetsCache",
    "ngMessages",
    "firebase",
    "angularMoment",
    "ngAnimate",
    "ui.bootstrap"
]);



(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("webpartner")
        .controller("webpartnerController",
            function webpartnerController($modal) {
                var vm = this;
            }
        );
})();
```

Comment: your modal is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of ui bootstrap in that plunker is an older version and uses `$modal`.

**It should be `$uibModal` with the version that you are using.**

Here's the documentation for the version that you are using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

...and a plunker taken from the documentation https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: this is not answer, this must be a comment

Comment: @Aravind No, this is an answer, and a correct one at that!

Comment: did u check the plunker?

Comment: @Aravind Of course, I wouldn't answer otherwise. The plunker is using version 0.11.0 of ui bootstrap. Kåre Rasmussen states that he is using version 2.3.1

Comment: Chnging $modal to $uibModal solved the problem in the app :-)

Comment: @KåreRasmussen glad to hear!